# Google Analytics does not show Pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, typo3

I have started to develop my first Typo3-Website.

To track interactions I have included Google Analytics with the following-code in the Setup-Section of the main-template:

```
page.headerData.9000 = TEXT
page.headerData.9000.value(
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-04738GHDL1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-04738GHDL1', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
</script>
)
```

With Google Tag Manager-plugin I am able to verify, that a global-site-tag is sent to my `G-04738GHDL1` tag

But I am not able to see anything in Google Analytics. Account and property is selected correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to anonymize the IP, it is a parameter not foreseen in GA4 since anonymization is always active.

So try replacing this:

```
gtag('config', 'G-04738GHDL1', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

with this:

```
gtag('config', 'G-04738GHDL1');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately this has no solved the problem... Is there a delay in GA after creating a new account?

Comment: it takes 24 hours to see the data, however from your site (from the link you placed) it does not seem that the data is being sent to Analytics. Try to put it in top of the page, after opening head tag.

Answer (score 0):

If the TypoScript Object page.headerData.9000 is not overwritten somewhere else in your TypoScript it should work fine. You can check the [TypoScript Object Browser](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/Debugging.html) in the Template module for that.

Set up correctly, the code should be output in your site's HTML.
From there I would suggest having a look at your browser's inspector tools, checking the console tab for any errors (e.g. regarding JavaScript errors or any [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) violations) and the network tab whether any request towards google are sent.
If you aren't familiar with that, the Google Chrome browser extension [Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-legacy-by-g/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) is quite helpful. ;)